# Is it possible select YouTube live chat components?

Tags: javascript, dom

Why YouTube live chat components cannot be selected using `document.querySelector`?
Is it purposeful or just a consequence of a framework used on the site? And how does the browser render it if it's not in the document?

For instance, if I open a YouTube live and click to get the CSS Selector of the chat text field I get this selector:

```
yt-live-chat-text-input-field-renderer.style-scope > div:nth-child(2)
```

And if try execute this in browser console:

```
document.querySelector('yt-live-chat-text-input-field-renderer.style-scope > div:nth-child(2)');
```

It returns `null`.

Is there a way to select this element? If not, how can I hide elements of my site to avoid scripts select them?

Comment: `document.getElementById('item-offset')` works just fine. Selects the container div.

Comment: the id of this element is "input", but trying to select using `document.getElementById('input')` also returned `null`

Comment: inner container at `document.getElementById('items')`

Comment: Is it in `iframe`?

Comment: Yes, it is in an `iframe`